# Вывод в текста в python в метод Text в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

В общем написал парсер, парсит он у меня погоду и мне надо чтобы по нажатию кнопки он всю информацию выводил в текстовое поле, но у меня пишет ошибку

> label.insert(1.0,pr)
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, RIGHT, BOTH, RAISED
import requests,bs4

pogoda=requests.get('https://sinoptik.com.ru/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0')#получение кода web-странцы в html
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(pogoda.text, 'html.parser')

mass_id =['bd1', 'bd2', 'bd3', 'bd4','bd5','bd6','bd7']#создаем массив для перебора вариантов

def pogoda():#функция parsing для передачи в кнопку
    for i in mass_id:
        poisk = soup.find('div', id=i).find_all('p')#подставляем id из массива и поиск тега "p"
        poisk1 = soup.find('div', id=i).find_all('div', class_='temperature')#подставляем id из массива и поиск тега "temperature"
        p1= poisk[0].getText()#считывание текста
        p2 = poisk[1].getText()
        p3 = poisk[2].getText()
        tm=poisk1[0].getText()
        pr=(p1+' ' + p2 +' ' + p3 + ' ' + tm + ' ')
        label.insert(1.0,pr)

root = Tk()
root.title("Weather")#название программы
root.geometry("270x200+300+300")

label = Text(width=20).pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)


ttk.Button(root, text='Узнать погоду', width=15,command=pogoda).pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка в том, что функция pack возвращает `None`, поэтому для запоминания объекта `label` запишите 2 строчки кода.

```
label = Text(width=20)
label.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Это не решение, а костыль, но работает

Вот как выводит ТК

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
from tkinter import *

import requests,bs4

pogoda=requests.get('https://sinoptik.com.ru/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0')#получение кода web-странцы в html
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(pogoda.text, 'html.parser')

mass_id =['bd1', 'bd2', 'bd3', 'bd4','bd5','bd6','bd7']#создаем массив для перебора вариантов

def pogoda():#функция parsing для передачи в кнопку
    data = ""
    for i in mass_id:
        poisk = soup.find('div', id=i).find_all('p')#подставляем id из массива и поиск тега "p"
        poisk1 = soup.find('div', id=i).find_all('div', class_='temperature')#подставляем id из массива и поиск тега "temperature"
        p1= poisk[0].getText()#считывание текста
        p2 = poisk[1].getText()
        p3 = poisk[2].getText()
        tm=poisk1[0].getText()
        pr=(p1+' ' + p2 +' ' + p3 + ' ' + tm + ' ')
        data = data + "\n"+pr
    v.set(data)

root = Tk()
root.title("Weather")#название программы

v = StringVar()
Label(root, textvariable=v).pack()


Btn = Button(root, text='Узнать погоду', width=15,command=pogoda).pack()

root.mainloop()
```